# Using pandas.read_table to read in a file as one continuous column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file-io

I need to load data from a file with many columns into my dataframe, and I want to read them in as one continuous column. This may sound strange, but it's really a way to get around poor formatting of the original file. The original file (let's call it parameter.txt) is formatted something like this but much larger:

```
 # parameter
10 9 8 6 5 3 1
9  7 6 5 4 2 1
10 8 6 5 2 1 0
7  6 5 4 3 2 1
```

I want the this to be a one column Dataframe (or Series) that I can concatenate with an existing Dataframe. So when I print it I want:

```
parameter
10
9
8
6
5
3
1
9
7
6
5
4
2
1
10
8
6
5
2
1
0
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

I've been trying something like this:

```
import pandas

existing_df = pd.Dataframe()

parameter_df = pd.read_table(parameter.txt, header=0, delim_whitespace=True, names=['parameter'])
existing_df = pd.concat([existing_df, parameter_df], axis=1)
```

...but I keep ending up with whole rows of text as each element in my final dataframe, plus a bunch of NaNs. Using squeeze=True doesn't work either. Help!

Comment: Maybe `parameter_df.stack()`?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The problem isn't the concatenation. Do you mean individual loading columns and then stacking them? Because that doesn't give the order I want which would be more like stacked rows.

Comment: You are not reading the data frame in correctly maybe, for your current code, the file is read in as one column. Don't you want it to be seven columns and then stack it to be a long column?

Comment: That might work if you have that solution handy.

Comment: Although there are hundreds of columns...

Comment: Do you have the *#parameter* in front of the file in reality or it's for demonstration purpose?

Comment: Yes, that's the real first row in the file.

Comment: You can check the option below to see if it gives what you need. The operation seems a little strange to me though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the parameters correctly with `read_table`. You can skip the first row if it is irrelevant and after read the file in, use `stack` to transform the data frame to long format, *a single row*:

```
parameter_df = pd.read_table("parameter.txt", header=None, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=1)

parameter_df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)

#0     10
#1      9
#2      8
#3      6
#4      5
#5      3
#6      1
#7      9
#8      7
#9      6
#10     5
#11     4
#12     2
#13     1
#14    10
#15     8
#16     6
#17     5
#18     2
#19     1
#20     0
#21     7
#22     6
#23     5
#24     4
#25     3
#26     2
#27     1
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: This doesn't work the way it seems to for you. I find that stack() just pivots everything and then the indices are reset but the output isn't the right shape.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your text file as a list `l` of integers and them read it as a Series.

```
 f = open('./parameter.txt').read()
f_list = f.replace('\n', ' ').split(' ')
l = [int(elem) for elem in f_list if elem != ''] 
parameter_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(l))
existing_df = pd.concat([existing_df, parameter_df], axis=1)
```

Is it what you want ?

Comment: This is too computationally intensive for my large files. It just ran for hours until I stopped it. :/